# Asynchronous Socket chat crashes on BeginReceive

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

This is console chat application is based on asynchronous socket. It crashes during BeginReceive:

The error is "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine." The antivirus is not the problem.

This is where Receive() is called.

```cs
static void RunClient()
        {
            // Connect to a remote device.  
            try
            {
                // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
                client.BeginConnect(remoteEndPoint,
                                    new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback),
                                    client);
                connectDone.WaitOne();

                while (client.Connected)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Input: ");
                        const string END_OF_FILE = "<EOF>";

                        string message = $"{Console.ReadLine()}{END_OF_FILE}";
                        Send(client, message);
                        sendDone.WaitOne();

                        // Receive the response from the remote device.  
                        Receive(client);
                        receiveDone.WaitOne();

                        // Write the response to the console.  
                        Console.WriteLine($"Response received : {response}");
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                    }
                }

                // Release the socket.  
                client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Edit: It works once, and then the error message shows.

Edit 2:

This is the Receive method.

```cs
private static void Receive(Socket client)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create the state object.  
                StateObjectClient state = new StateObjectClient();
                state.workSocket = client;

                // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.  
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,
                                    0,
                                    StateObjectClient.BUFFER_SIZE,
                                    0,
                                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback),
                                    state);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: What’s the error?  Why not use the much newer and easier ‘await ReceiveAsync’? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receiveasync?view=net-6.0

Comment: Can you provide an example of how this method is being called and how the client Socket instance is being created?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I am trying to follow the Microsoft example of asynchronous sockets.

Comment: Add this to the body of your question, not in a comment.

Comment: can you please show the Receive method

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is a fundamental misunderstanding of how TCP works.

TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol. The only gurantees for a TCP stream are

- the bytes you send will be received in the same order they are sent
- the bytes will be received only once

But you can send a message of 100 bytes and the other side can

- receive a 100 byte chunk
- 100 1 byte chunks
- 2 50 byte chunks
- ...

So you must keep looping till you have received everything. This is turn mean that you must know how big a message you expect. Either

- always use the same size
- prefix the message witha length of well known length (4 ascii bytes say)
- or have a recognizable end of message

---

How to do this

I assume that 'respnse' contains a string of the last received block.

```
 StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
 while(true){
           Receive(client);
           receiveDone.WaitOne();
           msg.Append(response);
           if(response.EndsWith(END_OF_FILE))
               break;
  }
  response = msg.ToString();
```

Not being able to see how you unpack the received bytes I hope the EndsWith is correct, maybe there is a newline of something tacked on te end

Comment: I have a recognizable ending, <EOF>.

Comment: @NLO3 I dont see your receive code looping though

Comment: the receive method is looped through in RunClient.

Comment: @NL03 no its not, you send a message then call receive then send then receive

Comment: What should I do instead?

Comment: @NL03 What I said, you need to keep looping, receiving until you see the end marker. First , you can confirm thats whats happening by dumping what you are receiving each time. I see you display what you received, is it complete?

Comment: I cannot understand you, could you explain further or show code of some sort?

Comment: @NL03 I will edit my answer

Comment: you cannot do stringbuilder += string.

Comment: @NL03 - correct, just making sure you're awake :-), my bad